# I have two tables and wanted to make a left join and get the latest data using date from both the tables. It doesn't pull all data from left table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables and wanted to make a left join and get the latest data using date from both the tables. It doesn't pull all data from left table

```
SELECT Firsttable.Username, Secondtable.city
FROM Firsttable 
LEFT JOIN Secondtable ON (Firsttable.Username = Secondtable.Account_Name)
WHERE (
        Firsttable.Questions <> 5
        AND Firsttable.CreateDate = '2018-02-06 09:41:38.000'
        AND Secondtable.CreateDate = '2018-02-06 09:07:47.000'
        )
    OR (
        Firsttable.Questions <> 5
        AND Firsttable.CreateDate = '2018-02-06 09:41:38.000'
        AND Secondtable.CreateDate IS NULL
        )
```

Comment: The `WHERE` condition on your second table turns your `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.  Think about this, when you say `SecondTable.CreateDate = 'Some_Date'`, it literally filters out any `NULL` values.

Comment: There's no relation between this two tables.
The relation must be expressed using the ON keyword.

Comment: Based on your WHERE clause you will not see all rows from the LEFT table where Questions <> 5 and CreateDate = '2018-02-06...'  Think about it logically, your result set contains all of those rows, then ELIMINATES the ones where Secondtable.CreateDate != '2018-02-06...'  What else is missing that you were expecting to see?

Comment: I want the rows from left table which matches the filter criteria and the latest date from both the tables. Still some rows are missing when I compared both the result with MS Access where I dont filter by date its just by questions

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide us with any data, you are going to have to do your own testing.

First, break your query down into smaller parts and see if the data you want actually exists.

```
SELECT Firsttable.Username
FROM Firsttable 
LEFT JOIN Secondtable ON 
   (Firsttable.Username = Secondtable.Account_Name
    AND Firsttable.Questions <> 5
    AND Firsttable.CreateDate = '2018-02-06 09:41:38.000'
   )
```

This will show if you have data in the first table that is valid.  If you don't get anything, you may need to relax your Date comparison by eliminating Time.  But only you know how restricting your data is.  It also may mean your `Secondtable.Account_Name` may not match up to your `Firsttable.Username` like you thought.  Play around with this query until you get the good data you were expecting.

Once you know you have good data in your first table, then add on selection criteria for your second table:

```
SELECT Firsttable.Username, Secondtable.city
FROM Firsttable 
LEFT JOIN Secondtable ON 
   (Firsttable.Username = Secondtable.Account_Name
    AND Firsttable.Questions <> 5
    AND Firsttable.CreateDate = '2018-02-06 09:41:38.000'
   )
WHERE (
    Secondtable.CreateDate = '2018-02-06 09:07:47.000'
    OR Secondtable.CreateDate IS NULL
    )
```

If this drops off all of your data, then you know something doesn't match up with your `Secondtable.CreateDate`.  It could be your use of Time is too constricting.  Just match on date only and see if that helps.  But if you know Time is important, go back to the first query above and print out all the different `Secondtable.CreateDate` to see if your date is part of the result set.  Being off by one second could cause your data to not match.

Play around with both of these queries until you find the combination that brings your data out.

If you still have trouble, you'll have to post some example data for each table so we can see how to help you better.